# Nginx + Docker + ASP Net core

Tags: c#, nginx, сеть, docker, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь обратно проксировать веб сервис на `ASP Net Core`.
Контейнер встает и все хорошо. Могу даже сделать `GET` запрос через `curl` находясь в другом контейнере:
[image: curl]

*Рис. 1 (нахожусь в контейнере с `Nginx`)*

`Nginx` тоже встает корректно и я могу вызывать другой точно также проксированный сервис (`/friday/`), но с одним ньюансом - он написан на `python`.

Конфигурации одинаковые практически, но при этом `/vkcore` возвращает 404 при любом запросе.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  fcore:
    restart: on-failure
    build: ./Friday_Core
    command: python3 main.py
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    links:
      - db

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8005:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx

  vkcore:
    build: ./Friday_VkCore
    restart: on-failure
```

Постарался налить только самой нужной конфигурации. Но вообще, т.к. я могу делать `GET` из контейнера в контейнер, то сети внутренние настроены правильно и проблема где-то в `Nginx`.

#### Конфигурация `nginx`:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
}


http {

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;

 upstream vkcore {
                server vkcore:80;
        }

 server {
    listen       80;

    location /supervisor {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://supervisor:6006;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }

    location /friday {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://fcore:7000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }

    location /vkcore/ {
        proxy_pass http://vkcore;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


  }

}
```

#### Примеры запросов из контейнера `nginx`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `error.log` у `nginx` кстати пустой

Comment: а у вас для .net случайно не влючен редирект на https (в стандартнов шаблоне он включен)? может .net приложение не знает, что оно стоит за проксей и шлет редирект на локальный адрес, который из вне не доступен?

Comment: `set $target http://vkcore:8005`?

Comment: @aepot а почему 8005, это же `nginx` на нем работает, а не `vkcore`?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ может, я конечно что-то путаю.

Comment: Выключал ее. @ExplodingKitten

Comment: @aepot, как сказали выше -- на порту 8005 работает `nginx`. Меня смущает максимально, что из контейнера `nginx` я делаю запрос в контейнер с `vkcore` и все работает так, как и должно, но при проксировании что-то ломается...

Comment: попробуйте `location /vkcore/`, чтобы правильно передавать query string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/how-can-query-string-parameters-be-forwarded-through-a-proxy-pass-with-nginx если нет, то скорее всего нужен полный конфиг, т.к. там могут  быть проблемы с default.conf

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, фокус не сработал, конфигурацию прикрепил

Comment: Нашел похожую реализацию: https://github.com/OllieDay/asp-net-core-nginx-https-docker-compose-example . Слизал чутка оттуда, все равно не работает. Завтра буду разбираться(

Comment: а теперь осталось вернуть `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` и должно работать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку я могу обратиться к сервису по пути `<URL>/threads`, а в `Nginx` я сначала обращался по пути `/vkcore`, то по итогу в сервис приходил путь `/vkcore/threads`.
Именно поэтому он и возвращал 404.

Решено путем использования `rewrite`:

```
location /vkcore {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    rewrite /vkcore/(.*) /$1 break;

    proxy_pass http://vkcore_stream;
    proxy_redirect   off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```